# How save multiple values from array in field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In model Project i have next array:

**PAYMENT_TYPE = ["in bar", "bargeldlose Zahlung", "E-Geld"]**

I have table projects with field **payments, type: string**

When i create new object(model Project)how me add values from array PAYMENT_TYPE  in field payments?

In view new.html.erb i added

```
<%= Project::PAYMENT_TYPE.each do |type| %> 
      <%= f.check_box :payment, :name => 'project[payment][]', type %>
    <% end %>
```

Displaying error: **/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/projects/new.html.erb:35: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting => ...=> 'project[payment][]', type );@output_buffer.safe_append=' ...**

full new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'Name' %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <P>
    <%= f.label 'Budget' %>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>

    für

    <%= f.select :price_category, Project::PRICE_CATEGORIES %>
  </P>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'Description' %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'Category' %>
    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label 'Skills Freelancer (15 pieces) *' %>
    <%= f.text_field :skill %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label 'Location' %>
    <%= f.text_field :location %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= Project::PAYMENT_TYPE.each do |type| %> 
      <%= f.check_box :payment, :name => 'project[payment][]', type %>
    <% end %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Anonymity order</b> 
  </p>
  Setup allows for players to remain anonymous. Note that this may reduce the number of responses.

  <p>
    <%= f.label 'Place Order anonymously' %>
    <%= f.check_box :anonymity %>    
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.fields_for :documents do |d| %>
      <%= f.label :attachment %>
      <%= f.file_field :attachment %>
    <% end %>
  </p>


  <P>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>    
  </P>

<% end %>
```

Comment: For future reference, "I" is always capitalised in English regardless of where it is in the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't google the correct syntax for this form, but you can't have naked hash params like you do except in the last parameter of a method call in Ruby. That is, your code is invalid Ruby.

Comment: where  invalid ruby, tell me please more detail? Why my form is not correct syntax? How correct in my situation?

Comment: Having `type` after hash parameters.

Comment: @StefanHansch by looking up the documentation. If you've done that and there's something you don't understand, explain what you don't understand.

Comment: i cant undestand how correct save values from array in field payment? I need create new table payment_types and save there values or how?

Comment: I give up. If you can't be bothered writing comprehensible comments, I can't be bothered helping you.

Comment: I have Table projects with filed payment_types with type string. In model project i have array: PAYMENT_TYPES = ['TYPE 1', 'TYPE2', 'TYPE3']. User can select one, two and etc. values with check box. How correct save this values in filed payment_types?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104829/discussion-between-stefan-hansch-and-andrew-grimm).